# Let $f_m(n) = f_{m-1}(n+1) - f_{m-1}(n)$, where $f_1(n)$ is the $n$-th prime number. Is there an $m$ such that $f_m$ is a constant?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$m$ and $n$ are positive integers. Will we eventually arrive at some $m$ such that $f_m$ has the same value regardless of $n$?

I want to know if taking $m$th-order differences starting with the primes will arrive at an $m$th-order sequence where all values are identical: differences between two consecutive primes, then differences between two consecutive differences of primes, then differences between two such consecutive differences and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math on your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Your definition works now.

My guess is that you are trying to define the [$n$-th differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) of the sequence of prime numbers. It's known that if a sequence becomes constant after taking $n$-th differences then it is polynomial, and the prime sequence is not polynomial.

Comment: It's easy to prove that the prime sequence is not polynomial.